# WPF Thumb in ControlTemplate can't be dragged

Tags: wpf, slider, controltemplate

I added a Thumb control in Canvas and it behaves just the way I want it to. Then I wanted to create multiple of these controls and I did it using custom class and a ControlTemplate.
The problem I have is that the code in the ControlTemplate is exactly the same as the code outside but the Thumb can not be dragged.

```
<Canvas x:Name="cnvs" Width="300" Height="300" Background="LightBlue">
        <Canvas.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type current:AnchorPoint}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type current:AnchorPoint}">
                            <Thumb Width="5" Height="5" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" Cursor="Cross" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
                                <Thumb.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Margin="-3"/>
                                            <Rectangle Stroke="Red" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Canvas.Resources>

        <Thumb Width="5" Height="5" DragDelta="Thumb_DragDelta" Cursor="Cross" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
            <Thumb.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Margin="-3"/>
                        <Rectangle Stroke="Red" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Thumb.Template>
        </Thumb>

        <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Name="pth"/>

    </Canvas>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Is your `Thumb_DragDelta` event handler being called?

Comment: I would create a CustomControl or UserControl that contains your thumb, so you avoid having the duplicate code and your drag event handler can be handled by the codebehind of the control fine...

Comment: Yes the Thumb_DragDelta event is getting called from the template. The sender is a Thumb and I do Canvas.SetTop and Canvas.SetLeft. The non template code calls the same code behind and it works properly.